# Cross domain tracking with redirect 307 - GTM

Tags: redirect, google-analytics, cross-domain, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

We have a domain e.g. abc.com, and we moved our content to abc1.com.
However, abc.com still exists like a directory of abc1.com content. A lot of visitors use our abc.com domain due to brand (about 60% of traffic). There are many links to abc1.com on the homepage abc.com, but links have 307 redirect.
Currently, we would like to track all visitors through both sites.
We use GTM to track and set

```
allowlinker = TRUE
cookieDomain = auto
Auto Link Domains = abc.com, abc1.com
```

We set Referral exclusion list in GA, too.

- abc.com, abc1.com

Probably there is a issue about 307 redirect. Does exists Cross domain tracking solution with 307 redirect?

Thank you.

Comment: Please can you elaborate about your issue?

Comment: Currently, cross domain tracking does not work with Redirect 307. Does exists some solution?

Comment: It took a moment to understand - user still may arrive at abc.com, but might be redirected to abc1.co after they have clicked a link, right ? Make sure that your redirect preserves the linker-Parameter that carries over the _ga-Parameter. This contains the clientid which then is used by abc1.com to proceed an existing session rather than starting a new one. This is essentially the same problem as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538027/google-analytics-cross-domain-tracking-does-not-work/37540820#37540820, i.e. whatever does your redirect must pick up and transmit the linker param.

Comment: @Antonín 'It doesn't work' is not a helpful or clear explanation of the issue at hand.

Comment: @JBrazier I meant "doesnt  work" that redirect break "session" and abc1.com generate new GA client.. and it problem for Cross domain tracking.. I need share client ID across domain..probably append as parameter to URL?