# Google Analytics Cross Domain Tracking does not work

Tags: session, cookies, google-analytics, session-cookies

When a visitor tries to do a booking, the site directs him/her to the booking engine site.

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-Y', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true });

ga('require', 'linker');

ga('linker:autoLink', ['mysite.com', 'bookingengine.com'], true, true);

ga('require', 'displayfeatures');

ga('require', 'linkid');

ga('send', 'pageview');
```

There are no errors or warnings.

I used a cookie monitor and it shows that browser creates another new _ga cookie when it loads the booking engine site. The same cookie ID is not used.

I was struggling for days changing code to `ga('linker:autoLink', ['mysite.com', 'bookingengine.com'], false, true);` but it did not work.

Comment: Just to get an idea what's going on, do you see the _ga parameter transferred to the respective other domain ? Are there any redirects or anything like it that may strip of the parameter (it's used to transfer the clientid between domains, so it is necessary that it arrives at your other domain).

Comment: Dear Eike Pierstorff, 
thank you very much for the reply
I cleared all my cookies and tried, the same cookie id was not maintained. two _ga cookies with 2 different IDs.
there are no other redirects

Comment: Dear Eike Pierstorff, 
thank you very much for the reply
I cleared all my cookies and tried, the same cookie id was not maintained. two _ga cookies with 2 different IDs.
there are no other redirects
you could check visit cantaloupehotels.com

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I see the problem. If you fill in the form on your main site and click you see the _ga parameter is not appended to the url that calls the booking-engine. Since  the parameter is necessary to transfer the clientid to the other site, where it is picked up by GA and used as clientid, cross-domain tracking cannot work - the GA code on the booking-engine does not find a _ga parameter in the incoming url and so starts a new sessions.

Usually the autolink plugin would add the parameter to the forms action. This does not work in your case since the form is actually submitted via a JQuery function (bookNow() in your functions.js file). This prevents the linker function from intercepting the submit event and adding the parameter.

The solution would be to add it yourself - get the linker parameter from the tracker object ([tracker.get('linkerparam')](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/linker#linkerparam)) and add it to the form action and add it to the redirect url in the booknow() function.

Comment: Dear Eike Pierstorff,

Thank you so much :D I'll do it now :D

Thanks again

Comment: Dear Eike,
I changed the code as you suggested (at www.cantaloupehotels.com -book now widget). Still, it doesn't seem to work, 
any advice on this would be a great help and thank you so much for your help so far. @Eike

Comment: I'll look into it (but alas not today as I'm  bit busy) .  Btw. You do not need to accept an answer unless it has actually solved your problem :-)

Comment: Thank you so much Eike! It means a lot to me :) :)